# Is the concept of "reference" different in C++ and Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, reference

Code in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string food = "Burger";

cout << &food << endl;

return 0;

}
```

The same code written in Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let food = "Burger";

    prinln!("{}", &food);
}
```

The output for the C++ program:

```
0x7fff604b2890
```

The output for the Rust program:

```
Burger
```

Why is this so? What am I missing?

Comment: are different languages different? Yes! Why? Because they are different languages.

Comment: btw I dont know Rust, but in your C++ code there is no reference

Comment: Concerning C++: Please, don't confuse the reference type with the address operator. `int &x;` <- This is a declaration. The meaning of `&` is reference. `std::cout << &x;` <- This is an expression. Now, the meaning of `&` is address-of-operator. (Nobody said that C++ is an easy to read language for non-experts...)

Comment: In Rust it helps to think of `&` as meaning "borrow" more than "reference".

Comment: I haven't encountered the C++ flavour of "reference" in any other language in use today. Like a lot of C++, it came from Simula 67. (C++ is more or less what you get if you add Simula 67 and CLU, remove garbage collection, and change the syntax from Algol to C.)

Comment: Oh! I mixed up the whole thing! My bad. Now, I get it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First thing first, in C++ the [`&` (address-of) operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) returns a *pointer*, that is, given `T t;`, `&t` will return a `T*`.

C++ does have references (`T&`), they are *not* created via the `&` operator, I'll point you to [this great answer for numerous differences between C pointers and C++ references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492/8182118).

Now to answer your question, **the concept of references is completely different between C++ and Rust**.

*Rust's references are fundamentally smart pointers*. If we go down the list from the link above, Rust references:

- can be initialised unset
- can be re-bound
- have their own identity (size, position in memory, …)
- can be nested
- can be dereferenced
- can be put into other things

They're also created using the `&` operator, which are all pointer properties.

Now while they're pointers they're not C pointers, they're "smart" because they're (type) safe, and thus like C++ references can't be `null`, or dangling. But that makes them safe/sane pointers. Across the board they still really behave as pointers more often than not.

As to what you are missing, the answer is that [`Display` (the trait used to format things) is blanket-implemented on references by delegating to the parent object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-82), so when you print "a reference" it's going to print whatever is being referred, because... that's way more useful, especially given how common references are in Rust (they're very, very common)<sup>[0]</sup>.

If you want the reference's "pointer value", you can use [the *pointer value* formatting specifier](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Pointer.html) (thanks trentcl):

```rust
println!("{:p}", &food);
```

(you could also cast to a raw pointer which is what I'd originally written but if you just want to print the value that's a lot more work for little payoff).

[0] to be fair other Rust smart pointers behave the same: `Box`, `Rc`, and friends all delegate `Display` to the underlying type

Comment: @tadman true, I've rewritten  point 1 to try and be less misleading, and make the difference between `&t` and `T&` clearer, does that look better?

Comment: There's a formatting specifier and trait explicitly for pointers: `println!("{:p}", &food);` will do the trick without having to cast to a raw pointer. The same works for other kinds of pointers, such as `Arc` and `Box`.

Comment: @trentcl true I'd completely forgotten that one, replaced the bits about casting with  & and a doc link, thanks.

Comment: You say that "[references] can be initialised unset", but also *"references can't be null, or dangling"*. I wonder how that works.

Comment: The compiler tracks the initialisation state of any local, and prevents their use: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32a9d9a599c3224b8b3b1d1c4dabf11e